# Can you view linked server properties in MS SQL server Management Studio without dropping server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

Why do you have to drop a linked server before you can make changes to the server? Why can you not view properties of the server i.e. username access rights etc? Is it practical to drop a table first before having the ability to alter it and make changes? Is it safe to use drop and create to in order to get properties of the linked server or will the settings be removed? Is there a SQL command that would allow you to view properties of a linked server?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can view the properties of the linked servers, and you may make changes on tabs #2 and #3. The first tab can not be changed, IE: server type and name.

To see the linked servers in MSSMS, look under "Server Objects", Linked Servers", then right click on the linked server and select properties.

Answer (score 0):

To check the properties of linked servers you can use:

```
EXEC sp_linkedservers
```